# Differences between null and StringUtils.isBlank()

Tags: java, null

I want to check if a String is empty or not and I would like to know the differences between the following and which one is better and on which occasions.

Specially because I'm getting this error if I use "isNotBlank": "cannot be cast to java.lang.String".

```
this.text.getData() != null <--- works perfectly fine.
StringUtils.isNotBlank((String)this.text.getData()) <- doesn't work.
```

If "null" is not the best solution, what could I use?

Comment: `StringUtils` is for working on Strings. Your `getData()` method does not return a `String`, so it's not applicable.

Comment: @RealSkeptic  shouldn't that be an answer?

Comment: Your method getData() can be return null. Is your method StringUtils.isNotBlank() include checking null value?

Comment: So the only correct way to check it would be with the != null? is there a "better way"?

Comment: @sharonbn There are people who  would write this as an answer, but I think it's more of a tip as to how the question itself is based on wrong assumptions, so the OP can consider whether he wants to change or delete or clarify it.

Comment: `StringUtils.isNotBlank` can only accept `CharSequence` (like String, StringBuilder, and so on). What is return type of `getData`?

Comment: @Pshemo If `getData()` would return String, the cast would work, even if null is returned.

Comment: "Text" as in  javax.xml.soap or in org.w3c.dom or in ... ? Please use full class names.

Comment: @laune That is obvious, I am asking it to make OP check it himself, and see for himself that something like `StringUtils.isNotBlank(getHorse())` doesn't make sense and we should try looking for solution like `StringUtils.isNotBlank(getHorseName())`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you expect any data that is not null to be a String then
`this.text.getData() != null` might work but your code will later
on have a class cast problem and the fact that the cast to String
is not working shows a deeper problem.

If it is OK for 'data' to be some object of some type, then 
`StringUtils` is simply not the right solution and the Null-check 
is the right thing to do!

Answer (score 3):

`isNotBlank()` Checks if a String is not empty (""), not null and not whitespace only.

> public static boolean isNotBlank(String str)
>   Checks if a String is not empty (""), not null and not whitespace only.

See  Doc [isNotBlank](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isNotBlank(java.lang.String))

`!= null` check only if the object is `null`

I'm getting this error if I use "isNotBlank" "cannot be cast to java.lang.String".

That's because may be your `getData()` return something other than String and that can't be casted to String.

And you need to know you can do `!= null` with any type of object but to do `isNotBlank()` it should be a String.